# BuddyBoss change filter "dropdown" into "buttons"

Tags: filter, dropdown, buddyboss

I want to transform the filter dropdown on the member directory with 3 filter options (newest members, recently active and alphabetical) into 3 separate buttons. So, in short, buttons instead of dropdown.
I have achieved to transform it into buttons but then all filter logic is gone and I dont know how to get it to filter like before. I dont change the button names or what they should do, in fcat they still should filter for the same thing what they filtered before only now as buttons and not dropdown.

Any suggestions?

ChatGPT cannot process many templates after another, it loses focus on the issue at hand.
Too many templates to deal with that are not logically rdered so I dont know what tp actually look for.